# Вызвать статический метод родительского класса

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
class signal:
    lst = []
    booklist = None
    data = [[0,  'nickname' , "nickname"],
            [1,  'name'     , "notempty"]]
    
    def __init__(self, row, nrow):
        for key in self.data:
            if check(row[key[0]], key[2], "Лист: " + self.booklist + " Строка: " + str(nrow)):
                setattr(self, key[1], row[key[0]])
                
    @staticmethod
    def exist(nickname):
        result = False
        for i in lst:
            result = result or i.nickname == nickname
        return result 
            
        
        
    
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
class di(signal):
    booklist = "DI"
    data = [[0,  'nickname' , "nickname"],
            [1,  'in'       , "in"      ],
            [2,  'category' , "int"     ],
            [3,  'log'      , "bool"    ],
            [4,  'name'     , "notempty"],
            [5,  'inversion', "bool"    ],
            [6,  'ton'      , "time"    ],
            [7,  'tof'      , "time"    ],
            [8,  'module'   , "notempty"],
            [9,  'cleath'   , "notempty"],
            [10, 'device'   , "notempty"]]
```

В теле программы делаю:

```
print(di.exist("P_cool_pg1_high"))
```

Получаю ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\and-work\Desktop\Медвежье СП\python\autogen_owen_1.py", line 197, in <module>
    print(di.exist("P_cool_pg1_high"))
  File "C:\Users\and-work\Desktop\Медвежье СП\python\autogen_owen_1.py", line 117, in exist
    for i in lst:
NameError: name 'lst' is not defined
```

Как обратиться к `lst`?
`lst`  - это кстати список экземпляров класса `signal`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно всё таки использовать @classmethod, просто указать класс cls при объявлении метода и далее cls.lst

Comment: А вы пользуйтесь какими-нибудь IDE? Просто, когда я вставил ваш код, мне IDE сразу подсветила `lst` в строке `for i in lst:`, мол неизвестно откуда тут эта переменная. Я использую `PyCharm`

Answer (score 3):

Используйте не @classmethod, а @staticmethod. Декоратор @classmethod первым параметром метода подставляет класс вызываемого метода.

Comment: Изменил на @staticmethod, изменил немного сам метод и получил другую ошибку.

Answer (score 2):

Используйте статичный метод, но в нем указывайте тип, из которого и будете получать значения:

```
@staticmethod
def exist(nickname):
    result = False
    for i in Signal.lst:
```

Если же вам важен в каком типе вызывается `exist`, тогда используйте декоратор `@classmethod`. Например, в `signal` и `di` могут быть разные списки `lst`:

```
@classmethod
def exist(cls, nickname):
    result = False
    for i in cls.lst:
```

В питоне, для именования классов используйте первую букву в верхнем регистре: `Signal`. Есть стандарт [pep8](http://pythonworld.ru/osnovy/pep-8-rukovodstvo-po-napisaniyu-koda-na-python.html), в котором хорошо описано как код питона сделать лучше.